# Правильное наследование std::exception

Tags: c++, gcc

Пытаюсь написать свой класс исключений

```
class MathException : std::exception
{
public:
    MathException(std::string &&whatStr) noexcept : whatStr(std::move(whatStr)) { }
    MathException(const std::string &whatStr) noexcept : whatStr(whatStr) { }
    ~MathException() noexcept;

    const char* what() const noexcept override;

private:
    std::string whatStr;
};

const char* MathException::what() const noexcept
{
    return whatStr.c_str();
}

int main()
try
{
    throw MathException("Parse Error");
}
catch(...)
{

}
```

На что мне компилятор вежливо отвечает:

```
error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for MathException'                                                                                                                                
error: undefined reference to 'MathException::~MathException()'                                                                                                                           
error: undefined reference to 'vtable for MathException'                                                                                                                                             
the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see go/missingkeymethod)
```

Comment: Что-то вы недоговариваете :) См. тут - http://ideone.com/8It9y2 - как видите, все скомпилировалось... Это ВЕСЬ ваш код? Приведите, pls, пример кода, который ведет себя так, как вы указали...

Comment: Вот пример http://ideone.com/FHnjUf

Comment: или даже без ? : http://ideone.com/xLzuFX

Answer (score 3):

Решение оказалось до боли смешное. Надо было всего лишь реализовать деструктор, либо сказать компилятору создать его: `~MathException() noexcept = default;`